Blazor WebAssembly Query Strings
What is the preferred method to pass a query string in Blazor Webassembly? For example, I can pass the integer ID, but that is easy to change. Or do I not use query string and use protectedSessionStorage?

"but that is easy to change"  should not be a problem.

on the admin side I access companies with the integer id, probably not going to be a problem, but just thinking of future cases. Otherwise, I can use uniqueid from the table.

Still not clear what you want to do or what the problem is.

I am coming from webforms and after I thought about it I do not need to encrypt a query string.

Blazor .net8 - In shared project declare class, Filename IHelpersRepository:
 public interface IHelpersRepository
{
    Task <string> ProtectData(string data);
    Task <string> UnProtectData(string data);
}

In client project declare class, Filename HelpersService reference   IHelpersRepository:
    public class HelpersService : IHelpersRepository
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public HelpersService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    //note this is returning JSON string which expects a string to start with { use the code below. Just return a string
    public async Task<string> ProtectData(string data)
    {
        var results = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/Helpers/ProtectData/" + data);
        string response = await results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //var response = await results.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>();
        return response!;
    }

    public async Task<string> UnProtectData(string data)
    {
        var results = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/Helpers/UnProtectData/" + data);
        string response = await results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //var response = await results.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<string>();
        return response!;
    }
}

In server project declare class, Filename HelpersRepository reference IHelpersRepository:
public class HelpersRepository : IHelpersRepository
 {
     string key = "AddYourOwnSpecialKeyHere";

     IDataProtector _dataProtector;
     public HelpersRepository(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
     {
         _dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(GetType().FullName);
     }

     //note this is NOT returning JSON string which expects a string to start with { use the code below. 

     public async Task<string> ProtectData(string data)
     {
         var protectedData = _dataProtector.Protect(data);
         return protectedData.ToString();
     }

     public async Task<string> UnProtectData(string data)
     {
         var UnprotectedData = _dataProtector.Unprotect(data);
         return UnprotectedData.ToString();
     }

 }

In server project add controller, Filename HelpersController:
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
//[Authorize]
[ApiController]

    public class HelpersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHelpersRepository _helpersRepo;
        public HelpersController(IHelpersRepository helpersRepo)
        {
            this._helpersRepo = helpersRepo;
        }
    
    
        [HttpGet("ProtectData/{data}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ProtectData(string data)
        {
            var res = await _helpersRepo.ProtectData(data);
            return Ok(res);
        }
    
        [HttpGet("UnProtectData/{data}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> UnProtectData(string data)
        {
            var res = await _helpersRepo.UnProtectData(data);
            return Ok(res);
        }
    
    }

Add to Program.cs on client:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHelpersRepository, HelpersService>();

Add to Program.cs on server:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHelpersRepository, HelpersRepository>();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();


To Protect call as follows From webassembly page:
@inject IHelpersRepository HelperService
string strID = await HelperService.ProtectData(ID.ToString());

To Unprotect call as follows:
@inject IHelpersRepository HelperService
[Parameter] public string ID { get; set; } = "";
string strID = await HelperService.UnProtectData(ID.ToString());


In Blazor WebAssembly, passing query string in url is easy but not secure, as anyone can easily modify the query string. with non-sensitive data, using a query string is fine.
You can use a uniqueid for more security.
Regarding ProtectedSessionStorage, it allows you to securely store data in the browser’s session storage, where the data is encrypted. So data will be safe and not exposed as it is in encrypted.
Here is the document you could refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server
Below is sample code i have prepared which shows how to use the unique id to securely handle query string.
Home.razor:
 @page "/"
    <h3>Blazor Query String Demo - Secure Handling</h3>
    
    <!-- Link to the CompanyDetails page with a GUID in the query string -->
    <a href="/companydetails?id=@companyId">Go to Company Details</a>
    
    @code {
        private Guid companyId = Guid.NewGuid(); // Generate a unique ID
    }

CompanyDetails.razor:
 @page "/companydetails"
      @inject NavigationManager Navigation
    
    <h3>Company Details</h3>
    
    @if (isValidGuid)
    {
        <p>Company ID: @companyId</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>Invalid or missing company ID.</p>
    }
    
    @code {
        private Guid companyId = Guid.Empty;
        private bool isValidGuid = false;
    
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            // Get the current URL
            var uri = new Uri(Navigation.Uri);
    
            // Parse the query string
            var queryParams = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);
    
            // Check if the "id" query parameter is present and try to parse it as a GUID
            if (queryParams.TryGetValue("id", out var idValue) && Guid.TryParse(idValue, out var parsedId))
            {
                companyId = parsedId;
                isValidGuid = true; // Validation successful
            }
            else
            {
                isValidGuid = false; // Validation failed
            }
        }
       }

This is just sample code for refernce.
Some other point to consider is always use the HTTPS url for security. And when you pass query string parameter make sure you validate that . In above example I have used Guid.TryParse  to check if it is valid or not. And if you want to avoid exposer or query string url better to use ProtectedSessionStorage or Blazored.SessionStorage.
You can choose the approach based on your project requirement.

Not really what I was looking for, got it working using IDataProtector and IDataProtectionProvider.

@user2648685 you could share your solution so that if others face similar issue in future it will help.

Jalpa - done see above.
